# Variable me imprime NaN en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo javaScript y a programar. Entré a HackerRank pero creo que tengo un erorr de Sintaxis porque desde mi punto de vista la lógica está bien (Creo). solo me dan para modificar la función "compareTriplets" Acá les dejo el código del problema `

```
// Complete the compareTriplets function below.
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    let resultado = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a[i] > b[i]) {
            resultado[0]++;
        } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
            resultado[1]++;
        }
    }
  return resultado;
}


function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const a = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(aTemp => parseInt(aTemp, 10));

    const b = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(bTemp => parseInt(bTemp, 10));

    const result = compareTriplets(a, b);

    ws.write(result.join(' ') + '\n');

    ws.end();
}
```

`

El problema es que al final solo me imprime esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes inicializar las posiciones del arreglo `let result=[0,0]` también tu condición no tiene `else` por ende no validara en caso de que los números sean iguales!

Comment: cómo haría en caso de que sean iguales? porque el enunciado dice que en caso de que sean iguales no se asigna puntos

Comment: a bueno, si ese es el caso esta perfecto como lo tienes!

Comment: Ya lo resolví, tenía que inicializarlo como decías, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para que la salida o resultado sea igual a [1,1] se le debe asignar un valor a resultado en las posiciones 0,1 de 0 para que en caso de que se cumpla alguna condición se le sume 1, entonces la función debería ser:

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
     
            let resultado = [];
            
            resultado[0]=0;
            
            resultado[1]=0;

            for (let i = 0; i <3; i++) {
            
                if (a[i] > b[i]) {
                    resultado[0]++;
                } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
                    resultado[1]++;
                }
            }
            return resultado;
        }
```